# What files are excluded by default from Ant zip task?

Tags: java, ant, zip

I'm running an Ant zip task to zip the whole contents of a directory on Unix systems:

```
<zip destfile="${deploy}/test.zip">
    <zipfileset dir="/home/mydir" />
</zip>
```

After the zip is created, and checking the contents, I can see that some config files, Visual Studio specific files and others like the Mac OS .DS_STORE file are left out the zip.

Is there any rule ant follows to decide what files will not be included?

I need to know in advance since I need to create a list of existing files on that directory before zipping (currently using Java). Right now I'm excluding all directories and hidden files (using File.isHidden() and isDirectory() methods) , but the list is still getting some of the file Ant lefts out (for example, vssver.scc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<defaultexcludes echo="true"/>
```

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/defaultexcludes.html

Note that this is used across all Ant taks that use filesets, not just the zip task.

Answer (score 8):

From [the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#defaultexcludes), or use Konstantin's solution to inspect your particular installation:

> There are a set of definitions that
>   are excluded by default from all
>   directory-based tasks. As of Ant 1.8.1
>   they are:
>
> ```
>  **/*~
>  **/#*#
>  **/.#*
>  **/%*%
>  **/._*
>  **/CVS
>  **/CVS/**
>  **/.cvsignore
>  **/SCCS
>  **/SCCS/**
>  **/vssver.scc
>  **/.svn
>  **/.svn/**
>  **/.DS_Store
> ```
>
> Ant 1.8.2 adds the folllowing default
>   excludes:
>
> ```
>  **/.git
>  **/.git/**
>  **/.gitattributes
>  **/.gitignore
>  **/.gitmodules
>  **/.hg
>  **/.hg/**
>  **/.hgignore
>  **/.hgsub
>  **/.hgsubstate
>  **/.hgtags
>  **/.bzr
>  **/.bzr/**
>  **/.bzrignore
> ```

Comment: This is also the reason why the Jenkins Clone workspace SCM plugin does not clone the `.git` directory. (see linked question)

Answer (score 0):

Excelent Ant Zip Task Reference is here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html