# maven-assembly-plugin not copying .git folder

Tags: git, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm using the plugin to copy over files, but it keeps ignoring the .git folder.

```
<fileSet>
    <directory>${project.build.directory}/xyz</directory>
    <outputDirectory>/Final</outputDirectory>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
    </includes>
    <filtered>false</filtered>
</fileSet>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.git` diretory is ignored by default. See [What files are excluded by default from Ant zip task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351564/what-files-are-excluded-by-default-from-ant-zip-task)

On the other hand, `.git` stores git repository metadata. It has nothing to do with the files you work on. Copying over it sounds bad.

Comment: I'm using the maven-assembly-plugin and I had earlier stumbled on that post and found out that while the git exclusion maybe true, the article itself does not help me. While generally copying over .git folders is bad, its not in this case.. just using it for version info and this copy over is to an intermediary location... so its coool :D